IBM MQ with multiple listener for same queue
We have Spring boot application which contains listener to listen the message from IBM MQ specific queue. We define the queue as below
define qlocal (Test) SCOPE(QMGR) MSGDLVSQ (FIFO) SHARE MAXDEPTH (9999) MAXMSGL(94304) DEFPSIST(NO) DEFSOPT(EXCL) DEFREADA(NO) CUSTOM('CAPEXPRY(100)')

When we scale our spring boot application to 2 we got the below error, after changing DEFSOPT(SHARED) we are able to scale the application. But the issue is like when there is message, it consumed by only one application(the last/first application started), message not distributed to all spring boot application.
JMSWMQ2008: Fai
QCC_FAILED') reason '2042' ('MQRC_OBJECT_IN_USE')

My requirement is I have spring boot application which listen message from IBM MQ and I can scale the application according to my demand. Any message on the queue must be listen by one application only and process forward. The same message should not be listen by both the application.

Please can you clarify the desired behaviour. The question states both "...message not distributed to all spring boot application." and "Any message on the queue must be listen by one application only...". The MQSC config shown is for a queue which suggests - in the case of a 'get' operation - you are looking for a single consumer to process the message?

You have specified DEFSOPT(EXCL) in your queue definition. This causes the queue to be opened by an application in Exclusive mode. When one application openes this queue with MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF, then no other application can open the queue and will receive MQRC 2042.
You will need to define/alter queue definition with DEFSOPT(SHARED) option.
See here for more details on MQRC 2042 - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.4?topic=codes-2042-07fa-rc2042-mqrc-object-in-use
